# javanullpointexception comparing dates

Tags: android, date

so in my code i have  to fill a form with data and one camp of that form is the date. i made a function that compares the date with 2 other dates that i receive from another class by bundle. this function also sees if the user has introduced new characters and if any edittext is empty and if it is doesnt shows the confirmation button. The problem is when i click the confirmation button twice i fill one form click it and it works i fill again and it throw a javalongnull pointer exception.

My code:

```
private TextWatcher myTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
  // invoke the following method here:
restricoes();


}
};

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.add_linha);



  //Download JSON file AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();



 Intent i = getIntent();
 id2 = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
 data = i.getStringExtra(DATA);
 data2 = i.getStringExtra(DATA2);




 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00:00"));
 java.util.Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
 SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
 //you can get seconds by adding  "...:ss" to it
 time.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00:00")); 
 String hr = time.format(currentLocalTime); 





  /** WebServices */
   inputdtestab= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editestab);
  inputdata = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editdata);
  inputhora = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edithora);
  quantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editquantidade);

   inputhora.setText(hr);



   inputdtestab.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
 quantidade.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
  inputdata.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);



/   / Create button
  Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

 // button click event
 btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // creating new product in background thread
    new CreateNewProduct().execute();
}
});





  change_date=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 change_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //triggers the DatePickerDialog
  showDialog(Date_Dialog_ID);
  }
  });



//getting current date
 cDate=Calendar.getInstance();
cDay=cDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 cMonth=cDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 cYear=cDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  //assigning the edittext with the current date in the beginning
  sDay=cDay;
 sMonth=cMonth;
 sYear=cYear;
 updateDateDisplay(sYear,sMonth,sDay);







   restricoes();




   }




 //restriçoes ver
 private boolean checkEditText(EditText edit) {
return edit.getText().length() == 0;
 }


  public void restricoes()  {
 int x=0;
Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
 datateste= inputdata.getText().toString();

ntln("How to get here?");
        }
```

try{

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date date1 = sdf.parse(datateste);
        java.util.Date date2 = sdf.parse(data);
        java.util.Date date3 = sdf.parse(data2);

        System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

        if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0 || date1.compareTo(date3)>0){
            x=1;
        }else{
            System.out.pri
    }catch(ParseException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

if(checkEditText(inputdtestab) )
{
inputdtestab.setError("yipikaei");
btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}else if(x==1){

    inputdata.setError("asa");
    btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
else if(checkEditText(quantidade)){

quantidade.setError("mudfukkerrr");
btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
else{

     // ==========================================
     // make button visible.
     // use the method "setVisibility", not "setViewVisibility"
     // and "VISIBLE" in "View.VISIBLE" is in full cap:
     btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

  }

  @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

  switch (id) {
  case 0:
  return new DatePickerDialog(this, onDateSet, cYear, cMonth,
  cDay);
 }
  return null;
   }


    private void updateDateDisplay(int year,int month,int date) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          inputdata.setText(year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+date);
      }



  private OnDateSetListener onDateSet=new OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
 int dayOfMonth) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 System.out.println("2");
  sYear=year;
  sMonth=monthOfYear;
  sDay=dayOfMonth;
  updateDateDisplay(sYear,sMonth,sDay);
 }
  };
```

logcat:

```
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ccc/pesagem.Newlin_ProductActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1001)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:620)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at pesagem.Newlin_ProductActivity.restricoes(Newlin_ProductActivity.java:246)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at pesagem.Newlin_ProductActivity$1.afterTextChanged(Newlin_ProductActivity.java:119)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
  06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at pesagem.Newlin_ProductActivity.updateDateDisplay(Newlin_ProductActivity.java:308)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at pesagem.Newlin_ProductActivity.onCreate(Newlin_ProductActivity.java:213)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
 06-15 01:26:37.743: E/AndroidRuntime(886):     ... 11 more
```

The problem is in here, the simplaDateformat, but i cant understand why:

```
 try{

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date date1 = sdf.parse(datateste);
        java.util.Date date2 = sdf.parse(data);
        java.util.Date date3 = sdf.parse(data2);

        System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

        if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0 || date1.compareTo(date3)>0){
            x=1;
        }else{
            System.out.pri
    }catch(ParseException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

if(checkEditText(inputdtestab) )
{
inputdtestab.setError("yipikaei");
btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}else if(x==1){

    inputdata.setError("asa");
    btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
else if(checkEditText(quantidade)){

quantidade.setError("mudfukkerrr");
btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
else{

     // ==========================================
     // make button visible.
     // use the method "setVisibility", not "setViewVisibility"
     // and "VISIBLE" in "View.VISIBLE" is in full cap:
     btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Which line of code is line 246 of Newlin_ProductActivity.java? A call to `parse` on that line is what's causing the exceptin.

Comment: sorry only saw now its java.util.Date date2 = sdf.parse(data);

Comment: Then `data` is `null`. It's likely that the activity is being called with an `Intent` that does not have the correct extras set. You need to either correct that problem (which would be in code that you haven't posted) or modify your logic to handle `null` values for those extras (or do both).

Comment: sorry but it isnt when i clik the 1 time on the button it works fine and i system.out.println the values and data is not null. i clik 2 time on the button and the app crashes and the error apears

Comment: Well, then `data` is `null` the second time. (This is assuming that this is indeed the line that is generating the NPE.)

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, it looks like either `data` or `data2` is null. Are you sure the Intent has those extras?

Without knowing exactly what your code does, it's hard to suggest a fix. If you just need to avoid the exception, you could do something like this:

```
java.util.Date date2 = (data != null ? sdf.parse(data) : new Date());
java.util.Date date3 = (data2 != null ? sdf.parse(data2) : new Date());
```

Comment: yes they have data, when i do the 1s time it doesnt shows any errors when i click the button, but when i click the navigation buton to go to the form activity t trhows me that error

Comment: A NPE there could only mean this, though. `getStringExtra()` can return null if the intent doesn't hold an extra for that key.